# How to test that SNI is supported by given webbrowser?

Tags: browser, https

I just want to test this:

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

on different webbrowsers. (if it's working or not)

I know I could Google HTTPS sites using the:

```
inurl:https
```

But how can I search for HTTPS domains that's on a shared hosting? (I mean that 1 IP is behind many-many domains.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a website just for that: **https://sni.velox.ch/**