# Firefox on Windows XP doesn't supports SNI?

Tags: firefox, https

Why do I get this message on Windows XP SP3?:

https://sni.velox.ch/

"Unfortunately, your client [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)] did not send a TLS server name indication extension (RFC 4366) in its ClientHello (negotiated protocol: SSLv3), so you're probably getting warnings about certificate name mismatches."

When I visit the mentioned site with Firefox.

So this means that Firefox doesn't supports SNI? Or What? :O

p.s.: it's related to: [How to test that SNI is supported by given webbrowser?](https://superuser.com/questions/303223/how-to-test-that-sni-is-supported-by-given-webbrowser/303267#303267)

Comment: Using Firefox 5.0 on Win XP SP3 and I get a positive result, could just be an "old version of Firefox" issue since I see `3.6.18` in your user agent string.

Answer (score 4):

Under *Tools* → *Options* → *Advanced* → *Encryption*, make sure you have "Use TLS 1.0" enabled. This is off by default in older versions of Firefox. **UPGRADE!**

Comment: Thank you. The Firefox version is 3.6.18 and I checked it, it was disabled! After enabling TLS 1.0 the test still doesn't works!! Why? :O

Comment: Try clearing the cache - most browsers remember the SSL settings they used for websites.